# Maximal likelihood Error/Syndrome table for $[16, 11]$ hamming code

Tags: matrices, coding-theory, parity

I think I have to start with a parity check matrix for $[16,11]$ Hamming code.
 $$H = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

How do I go about finding the syndrome decoding table?

If I understand it correctly, my syndrome table will contain all the possible permutations of 0s and 1s upto $2^{5}$. E.g. $00000,...,01111,...,11111$. 
Do I have to find out coset leaders for all 32 syndromes?.

If yes, how will the decoding work?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you need to find coset leaders for all cosets of the code in ${\Bbb F}_2^{16}$. So if a word $y$ is received, the syndrome $s=Hy\in{\Bbb F}_2^5$ is computed. Suppose $z\in{\Bbb F}_2^{16}$ is the corresponding coset leader, then the decoding gives the codeword $c=y-z$.